# Blocking Adult Content

Tags: google-play-store, stock-android, google-apps

I want to know how can I restrict access to adult content on my android phone  
What. Are the apps available in play store and is there any other permanent way to restrict such content on my phone. So that no one can ever ever get access to this kind of content on my phone.

Comment: There won't be any perfect solution (except for keeping the device offline). The closest you might get to that is a network filter (Firewall) in whitelist mode (i.e. only allowing for IPs/networks you explicitly whitelist), but that can be tedious to setup (and most likely requires the device to be rooted).

Comment: My device is rooted. Please tell me how can I do this

Comment: I've never played with that, so I cannot tell you which Firewall app is capable of that and how to configure it, sorry. For child protection, there are several [Content-Filter (Internet)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/childprotect#group_459) you could try – but they are usually restricted to the(ir) web browser. There are [Internet Firewalls](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_firewall#group_377) apps, but I don't know which one lets you have a per IP white/blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be changing the DNS server used by your device, by using a DNS server that doesn't resolve porn website hostnames.

You might need a rooted device to change the DNS.

An universal method to change the DNS is by using an app like **[SetDNS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.mytechie.setDNS&hl=en)** or  **[OverrideDNS](https://www.google.com/search?q=Override+DNS+apk)**.

Other methods for changing DNS is available here:
**[(GUIDE) How to Change DNS in Android Device (7 methods)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/xda-university/guide-how-to-change-dns-android-device-t3273769)**

A few DNS servers that don't resolve porn websites are:

1. OpenDNS:
   208.67.222.123
   208.67.220.123
2. Norton:
   199.85.126.20
   199.85.127.20

More here:
Source - **[5 DNS Services to Block Porn Sites without Installing Software](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-block-pornographic-websites-without-spending-money-on-software/)**

Answer (score -1):

you have to call your network and get it blocked, i know for 3 you can do it over the three app.

Comment: That would only work when you're using 3G, not for Wi-Fi.

Comment: you can tell your internet provider to block it too. my home internet is blocked for porno.